# setting alias for Java9

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc

I am new to bash. I have multiple java versions installed on my machine and I want to create an alias for all of them. Typically the executable for java is in folder /Library//bin/java. I want to create and alias so that I type java9 in bash and it executes executable for java9 (ad similarly for other java versions). How to do this.

Note typically for one javaversion I add JAVA_HOME and append the path in PATH. But not sure how to do this.

I was reading about this and looks like eval could be an option, but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javav () {
    local version="$1"
    shift

    case "$version" in
        8)  JAVA_HOME='/Library/some/path/java' \
            PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" java "$@"
            ;;
      8.7)  JAVA_HOME='/Library/some/other/path/java' \
            PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" java "$@"
            ;;
        9)  JAVA_HOME='/Library/some/other/path2/java' \
            PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" java "$@"
            ;;
        *)  printf 'Unknown java version: %s\n' "$version" >&2
            return 1
    esac
}
```

This is a shell function, `javav` (rename it if it clashes with any existing tool). You would put this in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file, or in its own file (in which case you would need to source it with `source filename`).

It takes a version number as its first argument and sets `JAVA_HOME` to the path of the appropriate directory, and `PATH` to include `$JAVA_HOME/bin` in the beginning before executing `java` with the remaining command line arguments. Since the `java` executable presumably lives in `$JAVA_HOME/bin` and since this is first in the `PATH`, that's the Java version that will be started.

This means that you use this like so:

```
$ javav 9 other arguments to java here
```

Assuming the function has been set up with the correct `JAVA_HOME` directory and `PATH`, this ought to launch Java 9 and pass `other arguments to java here` to the `java` executable.

Note: I'm not a Java developer, and I don't know if makes sense to set `PATH` the way I'm doing above, but you can modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanksfor the answer. I added it says javav not found. Tried to load it with source command still same error.

Comment: @Lovey Put it in its own file, then `source` that file. That would make the function available. If you make changes to the file, you will have to `source` it again. You would also need to update it with the proper paths of course.

Comment: Thanks It worked. Is there a way to load this function to bash profile, so that I will not have to source this everytime, whenever I want to switch env.

Comment: @Lovey You could add it in `.bash_profile` directly, or source it from there (or from `.bashrc`).